# how to apply join query using SQL

Tags: mysql, hql

I have 2 tables in a MySQL database.

The first table is 'property' with columns (id(pk), title, description, status)

The second table is 'object_property' in which all the relations between object and property is stored and their relation value, having columns (id(pk), object_id, property_id(fk reference column is 'id' of property table), value)

Now i want to extract a result of all properties from 'property' table where the relation doesn't exist in the 'object_property' table.

I need to write the SQL join query for this...

Can anybody help me out? I am new to SQL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were writing a raw query to run directly in MySQL you could use the following `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM property p
LEFT JOIN object_property op
    ON p.id = op.property_id
WHERE op.property_id IS NULL
```

If you were writing a query in HQL, then you would be dealing with *entities* (Java POJOs) representing tables, rather than tables themselves.  I can offer the following HQL query:

```
from Property p 
left join p.ObjectProperty as op
where op is null
```

This assumes that you have a class called `Property` which represents the `property` table.  It also assumes that the `object_property` table has an entity class `ObjectProperty`, and that `Property` has a reference to `ObjectProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select p.* FROM property p inner join object_property o on o.property_id!=p.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two tables,

```
table property ( id, title, description, status, primary key(id) )
table object_property ( id, object_id, property_id, value, primary key(id) )
```

where object_property.property_id is foreign key to property.id

You can join these tables to get the rows (tuples) that share a common key,

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.description, p.status, op.id, op.object_id, op.value
FROM property AS p LEFT JOIN object_property AS op ON p.id = op.property_id ;
```

You can use INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, depending on what you want to match, *but* here you want to find the rows in property that have id NOT present in the object_property table (the OUTER part of LEFT OUTER JOIN),

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.description, p.status
FROM property AS p
WHERE p.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT op.property_id FROM object_property AS op ) ;
```